# как можно сделать скролл у модалки, если при вытягивании его нету

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, frontend

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1vw;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 7vh;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  &__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    &-item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-right: 2em;
      list-style: none;

      &-link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #007bff;
        background-color: transparent;

        &:hover {
          color: #0056b3;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }

        &__svg {
          width: 5vh;
          height: 5vh;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


.container {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 80%;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.modal__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-state {
  display: none;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal-state:checked + .wrapper .modal-wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .wrapper .modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal .modal__inner {
  top: 0;
}

.modal__inner {
  transition: top 0.25s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: 50%;
  resize: both;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.3em;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -.3em 0 0 -0.7em;
  top: 0;
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
  background: #aaa;
}

.modal__close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 33.866cm) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 24.2cm) {
  .modal__inner {
    width: auto;
    height: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 35.6875cm) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 2vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 108cm) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <main class="main" id="main">
        <header id="header " class="header">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <ul class="navbar__menu">
                    <li class="navbar__menu-item">
                        <a class="navbar__menu-item-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__menu-item">
                        <a class="navbar__menu-item-link" href="#">Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__menu-item">
                        <a href="" class="navbar__menu-item-link__svg"
                        ><label for="modal-1">
                            <img src="assets/img/modal.svg" alt="">
                        </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
                        fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
                        cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
                        saepe similique soluta temporibus?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                <div class="modal">
                    <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-1"></label>
                    <div class="modal__inner">
                        <label class="modal__close" for="modal-1"></label>
                        <h2>Some Text</h2>
                        <p class="modal__inner-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum
                            dolorem ducimus expedita id ipsum iste omnis ut? Beatae,
                            blanditiis dicta, ea eaque fugiat in minima odit officia
                            praesentium, vitae voluptas.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer" id="footer">
            <p class="footer-text">copyright 2019</p>
        </footer>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Сам баг]

Comment: Некогда тоже думал над этим. Обернул блок и добавил скрол на него.